# end if statement

Tags: shell

Hi I have a simple question. How can I break the if statement?
for example

```
if [condition]
 then  **Iwant to to end here**
else
fi
```

I don't know what to use because break doesn't work.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to end?

Comment: @alex i want to end the if statement if the condition is true

Comment: @ms061210, _which_ shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking it wrong. If statement will only executed when condition meets and if doesn't meet, it will not get execute anything. But if you mean to jump somewhere else, you can use GOTO

like

goto TEST

TEST:

Comment: You've got a shell with a `goto`?

Comment: Well, `cmd` is a shell with a goto but, since it doesn't have that particular `if` construct, that's probably not the one desired :-)

Comment: thanks everyone for your answer :: Problem solved ^__^ REally help me sooo mucch :))

Comment: glad I could help, @paxdiablo, seems it was desired

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces around the command name `[` and before its last argument `]`.

You can invert the condition if you have a `!` operator (as in `bash`):

```
if ! [ condition ]
then : contents of original else clause
fi
```

Or:

```
if [ ! condition ]
then : contents of original else clause
fi
```

Or you can write the inverse of the condition:

```
if [ inverse-condition ]
then : contents of original else clause
fi
```

Or you can do nothing in the `then` clause:

```
if [ condition ]
then : Do nothing
else : contents of original else clause
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, `break` will only work inside a loop construct, either `while ... do ; ... done` or `for ... ; do ... done`

If you're code is inside a function, you can use `return` to leave the function from any place, including inside an `if .. ; then ... fi` construct.

OR if you're not in a function, then you'll have to use `exit`.

Assuming you're using `bash|ksh|zsh` there is no `goto :label`. That would be one of the few reasons to use the `[t]csh` family.

IHTH

Comment: thank you for your answer :) I try to use return and it works :)) thank you so muchh ^_^